# Problem reading light sensor value from Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to read Light Sensor value from raspberry pi, but all I get is Low or High:

```
using System;
using RaspberryPiDotNet;

namespace Test_PI
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GPIOMem ldr = new GPIOMem(GPIOPins.V2_GPIO_23, GPIODirection.In);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sensor: " +  ldr.Read().ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the reference of your light sensor ?

Comment: variable ldr is set to read value. I have solution, will post it later.